# Making a swich in java to control a Client/server procedure

Tags: java

I could use some help to create a switch statement so i can control my code. I have created a Client program in Java which can connect to a server / simulator.

When someone runs the Client program, it can start a so called "procedure" which will try to go from step to step and gather information.

These steps can be described like:

```
1. Verify Operator
2. Ask operator for item number
3. Ask operator to verify item name
and so on (there is like 8 steps, but i will only show 3 fornow)
```

So an example of my problem is that when lets say the operator sends back an item number to the client, which will be wrong in the example, i should make it so i can control which step i should run next.

Of cource if there is no problems or errors when running the steps, it should just go from 1 to 8., but if the entered item number is wrong, i should start from step 1 or 2.

I'm not sure how to do this, but i have tryed to create a switch statement somehow. Got a method called "runProcedure" which will start the procedure. Here i have created the switch statement like this.

**UPDATE:**

Now it looks like this:

```
public class Swich {

public int step = 1;
private int brutto;
private int netto;


public void runProcedure() {
    try {

        while(step != 4) {
            switch(step){
            case 1:
                //run "verify operator"
                System.out.println("Running step 1, checking brutto and netto");
                brutto = 50;
                netto = 100;

                if (brutto < netto) {
                    // program should just continue
                    System.out.println("Brutto/netto is ok!");
                    step = 2;
                    runProcedure();
                }

            case 2: 
                //run "Ask operator for item number"

                System.out.println("Running step 2");
                brutto = 50;
                netto = 100;

                if (brutto < netto) {
                    // program should just continue
                    step = 3;
                    runProcedure();
                }
                else {
                    // I should run case 1 or 2 again.
                    step  = 1;
                    runProcedure();
                }
                break;
            case 3: 
                //run "Ask operator to verify item name"
                System.out.println("Step 3 running");
                step = 4;
                break;
            default:
                //default
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I get it right, you're trying to check the `itemnumber == right`and when true, move on to the next step, otherwise go back to 1, maybe you can add a `while` loop to achieve it.

```
public void runProcedure(){
try {
    int step  = 1;
    while(step != 4) {
        switch(step){
            case 1:
            //run "verify operator"

            step = 2;
            break;
            case 2: 
            //run "Ask operator for item number"

            if (itemnumber == right) {
                // program should just continue
                step = 3;
            }
            else {
                // I should run case 1 or 2 again.
                step  = 1;
            }
            break;
            case 3: 
            //run "Ask operator to verify item name"
            step = 4;
            break;
            default:
            //default
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e) {
}
}
```

Comment: remember that `step!=4` is just for 3 steps  and for your 8 steps you may need to adjust it

Comment: Well, i guess you forgot to call the method again after making a step = 3 for example.. take a look , i have updated my thread, this is how a test switch is looking, and i think it works :)

now i can control what to run :D

Comment: I guess there is no need for this, after `step` is set to `3` for example, it will still go into the loop and execute `case 3`.